# MSBuild deletes .lib files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, linker

I recently added a few new projects to our Visual Studio solution. when I build the solution locally in visual studio (2010 SP1), everything is OK. but when I build the solution on our build machine (using script that calls `%DEVENV_PATH% "Solution.sln" /REBUILD "Release|Win32"` - also VS2010 SP1) some libraries (`.lib`) are missing from the output folder (those libraries should be created by the new projects I added recently).

I run the build again, this time with `procmon`, and I could see that after `link.exe` creates each library in the output folder, `MSBuild.exe` deletes the library. I looked in the project properties of the new projects to see if they are different from older projects' properties, but everything is the same (except for the output path). what could cause `MSBuild.exe` to delete the `.lib` files?